# Tooltip for internal comment links shows wrong title

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

Previously there was a feature requested to [add a title= tooltip to internal comment links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22305/automatically-add-preview-title-attribute-to-internal-links). This was recently marked as `status-completed` but was really only half implemented, as discussed in that post (how does one re-open an issue, anyway?).

Aside from the incomplete feature, there's a bug:
If a comment contains two or more links (ie. [this post's first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517428/coming-from-a-visual-studio-background-what-do-you-recommend-i-use-to-start-my-v)), then the tooltip for every link in the same comment has the same tooltip text, specifically the text from the first link.

Comment: Repro: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24571/clowns-have-big-shoes and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22305/why-is-there-no-giant-catapulting-contests-dwarf-tossing-only

Answer (score 1):

We aren't going to do an additional database lookup on every comment URL. The current implementation should suffice.

Comment: It's a good, light-weight fix. Plus, "Opera".

Comment: I am torn. On the one hand, I hate Opera. But on the other hand, I like you. :)

Comment: I'm not suggesting a database lookup for every comment link, but an in-memory LRU cache of (question_id, title) pairs seems like it ought to do the trick. But hey, it's your code. :)

Comment: @Hewgill http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24571/why-would-you-want-to-mess-with-a-feature-like-this ?