# Wrong title attribute on links on comments

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Page title from First url in comment is used for title text of all additional urls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34611/page-title-from-first-url-in-comment-is-used-for-title-text-of-all-additional-url)
>   [Tooltip for internal comment links shows wrong title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24571/tooltip-for-internal-comment-links-shows-wrong-title)

When on the [unofficial ad gallery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-ad-gallery/), I noticed something odd a comment of mine:

[image: example of tooltips]

I fired up Firebug, and sure enough, the http://contexts.org link had a `title` attribute set to `open source advertising sidebar 1h 2010`, which is correct for the previous link, but wrong for the second one.

---

### Edit

You can see that this problem is reproducible on the comments to this question.

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1rlThKe1qo">youtube.com/watch?v=k1rlThKe1qo</a>
<a title="these are not the droids you are looking for" rel="nofollow" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120542/these-are-not-the-droids-you-are-looking-for/">stackoverflow.com/questions/1120542/…</a>
<a title="these are not the droids you are looking for" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1rlThKe1qo">youtube.com/watch?v=k1rlThKe1qo</a>
<a title="these are not the droids you are looking for" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1rlThKe1qo">youtube.com/watch?v=k1rlThKe1qo</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120542/what-is-the-best-plotting-library-for-python/ http://wave.google.com/

Comment: Wow, Google Wave (TM) really does know *everything!*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120542/these-are-not-the-droids-you-are-looking-for/ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1rlThKe1qo

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1rlThKe1qo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120542/these-are-not-the-droids-you-are-looking-for/ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1rlThKe1qo http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1rlThKe1qo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120542/these-are-not-the-droids-you-are-looking-for/ These are not the droids you are looking for http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1rlThKe1qo

Comment: Duplicate (edit: or at least related): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34611/page-title-from-first-url-in-comment-is-used-for-title-text-of-all-additional-url

Comment: It's not a nice find anymore.

Comment: @Jon: you are correct. There is also a mention on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24571/tooltip-for-internal-comment-links-shows-wrong-title