# Auto-lookup of page/site title for external links posted in WMD

Tags: feature-request, editor, hyperlinks

Most of the times, when I paste a link I do:

1. Click on the "link" icon at the toolbar
2. Paste the link
3. Enter the link title

While step three is not too problematic I would like to skip it.

Could we insert the page title, back from step 2, so the next time we enter a link it appears like this:

```
Like Jeff said in [Stack Overflow Outage - Blog – Stack Overflow][1]

[1]: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/stack-overflow-outage/
```

And from there we can put what ever we want ( just like today ) ie

```
Like Jeff said in [the latest blog][1]

[1]: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/stack-overflow-outage/
```

If needed, or just leave it like that ( as I will do  most of the times)

Answer (score 2):

Another method to entering links is to highlight the words in your post and then fire up the help dialog to enter in the hyperlink.

Saves on the server having to go and do a fetch and parse of the page (which may or may not be possible depending on what you're linking to).

Maybe get into the habit of flipping your steps around:

1. Enter the link title
2. Click on the "link" icon at the toolbar
3. Paste the link

Answer (score 0):

This was [suggested earlier as an enhancement to markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22305/automatically-add-preview-title-attribute-to-internal-links) -- just including the link in the text would automatically translate to the correct markup with title preview.

Comment: That's for internal links.