# Rewriting "local" URLs automatically

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks

I think that URLs like `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-we-tag-questions` could be automatically rewritten by Stack Overflow and other sites into a nicer form. It could be something like:

- [MSO: Why do we tag questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-we-tag-questions), or
- [Meta Stackoverflow #31776](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-we-tag-questions), or even for the answers:
- [MSO: "Why do we tag questions?" Smurfsnorting Farfulburger's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-we-tag-questions/31779#31779)

Currently when people post links to other questions, the links are simply not very clear. It's even worse if someone uses the whole link in the comment field.

If anyone supplies a custom text, it should be left there of course - I only mean rewriting for bare URLs.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate, but I can't find what it's a duplicate of.

Comment: I tried to find something similar before posting, but found nothing :/

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22305/automatically-add-preview-title-attribute-to-internal-links

Comment: @Greg: Not really, that's about the tooltip titles, this is about adjusting the text altogether when you only enter a URL (and don't use Markdown for the link). In other words, you type a Trilogy URL, and the system decides rather than just linking it to pull & format the text, then link that.

Comment: @Greg: it's not - rewriting the link text itself was not officially requested there. One answer suggested it, but was not a request in itself. I addressed the "visible domain" problem here, by suggesting a tag. My main point is that local links look ugly when they're shortened in the comments (like yours) and are not clear enough in other places. So no - I knew about that post and I don't agree it's a duplicate.

Comment: Implemented [since November 2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer from November 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69483/295232):

> For intra-site links (like, SO -> SO) this is now supported.
>
> ```
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-sandbox
> ```
>
> becomes*
>
> [Introducing the Stack Exchange Data Explorer aka SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-sandbox)
>
> Like with [tag rewrites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482) this is done on post submission <s>and is not currently reflected in the editor preview</s>. It will always insert the current title into the post, at post creation time. However, should the title subsequently change it will not be updated unless the post is edited.
>
> <sub>*Note that although the **old** title of the question is in the link, the new one is inserted.</sub>