# Automatically populate title in all internal links

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

It would be nice if all internal links had the title tag auto populated, so instead of:

- [Advanced Syntax Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010)
- [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010)

You would have: (hover for effect)

- [[Advanced Syntax Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010)
- [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010)

Comment: Can somebody explain the 4 close votes

Comment: They're requests to close as a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/advanced-syntax-ideas, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4715/provide-a-way-to-quickly-link-to-a-question-within-markdown, and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22305/automatically-add-preview-title-attribute-to-internal-links

Comment: @Greg, I admit your question is mostly a dupe of mine, but the functionality described here is clearly not in place yet your question is marked complete.

Comment: Although my question is marked as complete, it's not *actually* complete as demonstrated in the question and comments.

Comment: just a test comment to see what's going on..

Comment: I guess this has been implemented, since it looks like it works in the example given