# Suggestion: a way for linking a chain of questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, related-questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically track referenced questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44643/automatically-track-referenced-questions)

it has happened to me that after some answers to my question, i had got an idea of what is my problem and my question have basically changed;
in such cases i felt a need to create a new question but tell the SO that this is in continue of the previous, so users can see the previous answers as well, and i don't be forced to edit my existing question.

is it a need to you too? or is it a good idea?
and what's the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

***You*** can link to your previous questions. It's the little "world" icon.

That said, there are limits of how small a change calls for a new questions (i.e. sometimes you should edit) and on the degree to which users are going to be willing to go back and look at previous questions (i.e. at some point we expect you to go off and think for a while).

Other than that, knock yourself out.